# webGL or voxel.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm studying JavaScript because I want to make voxel games (like minecraft type style) eventually. I've been told to use WebGL, but I've seen a lot of examples of minecraft type games using voxel.js.

So which should I use? Which one is better for voxel based web games?

Answer (score 1):

"Which *X* is better" is rarely a good question. It depends on what you're trying to do, what you already know, your personal tastes, and a lot of other things.

That said:

voxel.js itself uses WebGL.

If you *don't* use voxel.js, you're going to have to roll your own voxel framework. That's a significant undertaking that will distract you from focusing on gameplay.

I haven't coded anything significant with voxel.js, but I've experimented with it, and it seems to be really solid. Also, it's still under active development, so its capabilities will only grow. Unless you need a specific feature that someone hasn't already written a voxel.js module to handle - and you don't want to write that module yourself for some reason - using voxel.js is the sensible choice.

So I'd say, don't reinvent the wheel. There's already a free, high-quality solution to your problem.